# Wordpress returns 404 on a https request though file exists

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, https

We have wordpress installed with revolution slider. There is a request for a captions.php file over HTTPS. The request returns 404 though the file exists. It worked before we've install HTTPS so I my believe is that the request is some how not fully completed.

Complete error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). https://www.domain.dk/wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/css/captions.php?rev=4.3.3&ver=4.2.3"
```

I can't access the file directly. Not even with a `die();` But I am guessing that wordpress is rewriting all url's so i can't pass any php files absolute?

Any ideas why? I have included a screenshot of the console[image: Error in console]

Comment: Probably https is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Lol. I found that in my htaccess file there was typed "deny from all" -.- . Outcommented that and it all worked...

Comment: It's often due to FW rules injected into your .htaccess by a security plugin.